# JTextPane not updating after values changed

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Code is underneath. Basically what I'm trying to do is I have display going on in my JPanel of a JTextPane. I have a button that edits the value of the string that's supposed to be displayed in the JTextPane. I can't figure out how to update the JTextPane however. I've tried revalidate(), validate(), repaint(), none of those seemed to work.

The code is complete, it should be able to run.

import java.awt.Canvas;

```
public class windowBuild extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private int health = 20;
private int energy = 4;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            windowBuild frame = new windowBuild();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String which = e.getActionCommand();
        if (which.equals("Claw")){
            energy = energy-1;
            System.out.println("Player one's dragon clawed the opponent. Dragon's energy is now at: "+ energy);}
        else if (which.equals("Wait")){
            System.out.println("Turn succesfully skipped");}
        System.out.println(getEnergy());



    }

}


public windowBuild() {
    ButtonHandler bh;
    System.out.println("Starting frame...");
    bh = new ButtonHandler();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Dragon Duel",
            TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, Color.CYAN));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnClaw = new JButton("Claw");
    btnClaw.setBounds(288, 511, 109, 39);
    contentPane.add(btnClaw);
    btnClaw.addActionListener(bh);
    if (energy == 0)
        btnClaw.setEnabled(false); 
    JButton btnWait = new JButton("Wait");
    btnWait.setBounds(645, 511, 109, 39);
    contentPane.add(btnWait);
    btnWait.addActionListener(bh);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String strB = Integer.toString(health);
    sb.append("H: ").append(strB).append("/20");
    String healthString = sb.toString();

    JTextPane txtpnH_1 = new JTextPane();
    txtpnH_1.setEditable(false);
    txtpnH_1.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    txtpnH_1.setText(healthString);
    txtpnH_1.setBounds(134, 511, 109, 39);
    contentPane.add(txtpnH_1);

    String strR = Integer.toString(energy);
    String energyString = "E: ";
    energyString += strR;
    energyString += "/4";

    JTextPane txtpnH = new JTextPane();
    txtpnH.setEditable(false);
    txtpnH.setText(energyString);
    txtpnH.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    txtpnH.setBounds(39, 511, 85, 39);
    contentPane.add(txtpnH);

}


}
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: have you tried txtpnH.setText(newInfo) ?

Comment: `setLayout(null)` is my first area of concern, this is just going to make you like more difficult in the long run

Comment: @MadProgrammer Unless your code is generated by an IDE.

Comment: @tbodt Still, going to explode in your face the first time you try and run it on a system it wasn't designed for

Comment: I've had that experience with a calculator before. It looked right in the IDE, but not in real life.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used windowBuilder to intially add my buttons and layout. I believed I used AbsoluteLayout? Not sure if it went through.

Comment: @DavidPitre I tried it, couldn't seem to have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the time to read through the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)
2. Make use of appropriate layout managers, see [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more details
3. For what it's worth, use `JTextField` instead `JTextPane`, you're gaining little to no benefit by using `JTextPane` for what you seem to be trying to achieve.  In fact, you might actually be better of us just using `JLabel`, seen as you don't want them to be editable
4. Avoid overriding top level containers, like `JFrame`, instead start with something like `JPanel`, build your UI on it and then deploy it to what ever top level container you want.

The problem you have is a reference issue.  In the constructor of your `windowBuild`, you are defining all your UI components.  This means that there is no way you can reference them anywhere else from with your program.  Instead, make those components you need to reference else where instance fields.

```
public class WindowBuild extends JFrame {
    //...//
    private JTextPane txtpnH_1;
    private JTextPane txtpnH;

    //...//
    public WindowBuild() {
        //...//
        txtpnH_1 = new JTextPane();
        //...//
        txtpnH = new JTextPane();
        //...//
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String which = e.getActionCommand();
            // Now you can use txtpnH_1.setText and txtpnH.setText
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, a downvote - curious to understand why?  How does it not answer the question?  How could it be improved?  Since I'm not seeing any other answers I can only surmise that either you don't understand the question or you don't understand the answer :(